# How do I keep folder integrity when compressing files in different folders

Tags: windows, batch, 7-zip

I have a batch file that runs on our dedicated servers every day and compresses the files.

Here is a piece of the batch file:

```
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\*.txt >>%LOGFILE%
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\spoolq.q >>%LOGFILE%
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\vblib\shared\settings.cfg >>%LOGFILE%
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\sssusers.d >>%LOGFILE%
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\#library\*prt.cfg >>%LOGFILE%
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\#library\printer.txt >>%LOGFILE%
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\#library\netuse.text >>%LOGFILE%
%SUBDIR%7z a -tzip %fullname%  %datapath%\*.cfg >>%LOGFILE%
```

The batch file is getting the files that I want but they are all in the same directory and not in their original directories.

I tried `7z x filename.zip` when I extracted the files but that did not give me any different results.

Do I have to specify an switch when compressing?

Thanks for the help!

**edit**

I just realized I am telling 7z to put that file in the archive just as it is. I realize that now so my question really is, is there a way of keeping the original folder structure when compressing the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty weak but you have to use relative paths with no drive or leading backslash.
In your example `%datapath%` needs to have `"users\johnny\filespec"` rather than `"c:\users\filespec"`.

```
Cd \
7z a –tzip myzip.zip users\johnny\tmp\tmp2\TMP2.TXT
```

Will store the folder structure.

Then, from the same folder you zipped it up, you can unzip it with . ..

```
7z x myzip.zip
```

and 7z will put it back with the folder structure.

Beware, you have to unzip from the same folder you zipped because the folders will be created under your current location.